# Initially hide elements in ListView (uses ICollectionView and ObservableCollection)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection, icollectionview

I am using a ListView which is bound to a ICollectionView (ListCollectionView -> ObservableCollection)
While loading a file containing data the collection gets filled.
Every data item has a boolean flag, which indicates if it must be shown in the listview or must be hidden.

Currently I have done this in an ugly way. I am filling first the collection (listview) with data.
The user can see this. 
After filling it I start a routine which filters (ICollectionView.Filter) the items, which do not match.
The listview item count shrink at that moment.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

Just set the Filter *before* you start filling the collection:

```
ObservableCollection<Foo> collection = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView();
view.Filter = YourFilterMethod;
// Fill the collection
collection.Add(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is it not possible to use a kind of condition? The Listview shows only items which have a matching condition (a boolean property is true/false)